# Multiple imputation in repeated measurements setting?

Tags: logistic, large-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, splines

I'm working on a large database (2 000 000 observations = people, with 50+ variables), with the objective to estimate how a binary exposure E affects a binary outcome Y (a disease) using logistic regression, adjusting for 10 confounders X1, ..., X10. Some of the confounders are binary, some are continuous.

Exposure E = 1 and outcome Y = 1 are both fairly rare events (< 5% of cases each),

Problems:

1) Both binary and continuous confounders have missing values (roughly 75% complete cases) and

2) the observations are correlated in clusters of 1-10 observations (people within the same family, so varying).

Is it possible to use multiple imputation combined with mixed effects models/GEE, to account for both the missing data and the multiple measurements?

All I've been able to find is MICE package (in R) which allows for mixed effects models using mice.impute.2L.norm(), but unfortunately this doesn't seem to support the use of restricted cubic splines (not compatible with Frank Harrell's rms package). Also, I've understood there might be computational issues because of the large database if using mixed effects models rather than GEE.

What are my options? Help much appreciated!